# Add Date filter in object-manager

Tags: magento2, sales-order, object-manager

I have Code for getting all order But I want date filter in Object-manager. How Can I add date filter in it. I tried but I got Blank array. 
I am using Object manager in the script so I am suitable with this Way.

```
 $startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2018-1-1')); // start date
 $endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2018-12-12')); // end date              

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework \App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate)); 
 $orderDatamodel->getSelect()->order('entity_id DESC');
```

Comment: Can you give me the whole code? Thank in advance.

Comment: Sorry folks Code ok but the problem in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2018-12-27')); // start date
$endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2018-12-28')); // end date   

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework \App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate)); 
 $orderDatamodel->getSelect()->order('entity_id DESC');
```

Comment: I think our code is the same.

Comment: yes. end date was wrong.It should be $endDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2018-12-28'));

Comment: Sorry to say but still got an empty array.

Comment: where did you using the code, Out of Magento code base? please confirm, Make sure you change the Form and To date. Also, check any order actually exist or not within the date range.

Comment: yes orders are also there and when you remove "->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));" part code run prefactlly.

Comment: My Mistake Sorry dude its data issue Our code is correct. And thanks for confirm it.

Comment: @Krunal Pandya Welcome.